# How to make sign-up in django with one-to-one model?

Tags: python, html, django, view, model

I succeeded in registering as a member with this code, but the data is not included in the department of the profile.

my code is below(edit at 8:53 am)

model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
department = models.CharField(max_length=100)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

view

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            print(request)
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'new_user':user})
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()

        return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':user_form})
```

form

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['department']
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('',
     IndexView.as_view(),
     name='index'),
 path('register/', views.register, 
      name='register'),
 ....
```

template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<div class="container my-3">
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="username">ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username"
               value="{{ form.username.value|default_if_none:'' }}">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"
               value="{{ form.password.value|default_if_none:'' }}">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="password2">PASSWORD_CONFIRM</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" id="password2"
               value="{{ form.password2.value|default_if_none:'' }}">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
               value="{{ form.email.value|default_if_none:'' }}">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email">DEPARTMENT</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" id="department"
               value="{{ form.department.value|default_if_none:'' }}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">REGISTER!(SIGN UP!)</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

what should I do?
No matter what I do,

the department value does not go into the profile db.

The Register button exists in base.html

It took me three days, but I couldn't find a way.

s it right to make sure I made a model or view?
I'm still confused because I don't understand about instance.However, it's a situation that we need to implement membership.

I succeeded in registering as a member with this code, but the data is not included in the department of the profile.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not saving both forms in your views.py

Comment: I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: You have two forms and you’re only saving one of them. When you say commit=false you’re not saving it you’re getting the object back for further editing.